# conversion from hsl to rgb

Tags: php

Is there a way to convert hsl colors to rgb colors on the fly? i searched for this function in the documentation but nothing like this seems aviable at the moment. is there a way to create a custom function for this where the conversion is made as easy as `$rgb = hslrgb($hsl)` where both $hsl and $rgb arrays of the corresponding values?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure its possible... functions are made for this! that's what i regularly use to make this type of conversion. Its accurate enough, even though i'm rounding some values ;) it's fast on the other hand though!!

```
function hsl2rgb ( $hsl )
{
    $h = $hsl[0]; $s = $hsl[1]; $l = $hsl[2];

    $m2 = ( $l <= 0.5 ) ? $l * ( $s + 1 ) : $l + $s - $l * $s;
    $m1 = $l * 2 - $m2;

    $hue = function ( $base ) use ( $m1, $m2 ) {
        $base = ( $base < 0 ) ? $base + 1 : ( ( $base > 1 ) ? $base - 1 : $base );
        if ( $base * 6 < 1 ) return $m1 + ( $m2 - $m1 ) * $base * 6;
        if ( $base * 2 < 1 ) return $m2;
        if ( $base * 3 < 2 ) return $m1 + ( $m2 - $m1 ) * ( 0.66666 - $base ) * 6;
        return $m1;
    }

    return array( $hue( $h + 0.33333 ), $hue( $h ), $hue( $h - 0.33333 ) );
}
```